# PhD in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, soft-question

I am at the very beginning of a PhD which should be in complex analysis.
Now I'm going to decide on what I should work on.

My question could be vague, but it couldn't be different.

I love the classic complex analysis in one variable, special functions, integral transforms, continued fractions (I know there exists a link between generalized continued fractions and holomorphic functions), Galois theory, Group theory, and something from Representation theory.
Then here on MSE sometimes I see Lambert W function, polylogarithmic functions, digamma functions which are so sexy to me.

Can someone experienced suggest me some direction to follow? Some research topic? Some book/article to read? Some "slice" of Mathematics which embraces the pointed subjects?

Comment: I strongly recommend consulting the faculty at your institution. Take a couple of complex analysis classes, and see what seems interesting to you; then talk to the instructor, and ask them who you should talk to about those topics. In my experience, most math professors love to talk to grad students about their work, and they all have excellent recommendations about resources to consult.

Comment: Thank You, I will certainly do this!

Comment: @Joe To second Reese's comment, a very large part of being a graduate student is *learning from your faculty*. Find someone that you can learn from, whether as an advisor or through a reading course or through seminars. Unfortunately, such important guidance questions are off-topic here.